# Disable WordPress Custom css section on WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-admin

Anyone can help me to locking/ disabling the Appearance -> Customizer -> Additional CSS area.
on Wp-admin.

[image: Screenshot]

I read this codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API
But didn't got any hook or function for disabling it.
Actually, I don't need this, anyone developer's adding unnecessary CSS from here and this saving on the database. 
Please suggest any solution, If that is possible to do.

Thank you in advance for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try removing the section using the WP Customizer function hook:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize )
{
   $wp_customize->remove_section('custom_css');
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Obviously you can name the function to suit, but call this block in your theme's functions.php file and it should remove this admin section (it most likely has an ID of 'custom_css' but could potentially vary)

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/remove_section#Parameters